# "Subset" injectivity

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there any formal name for the following concept?

Say, we have a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ where $\exists S \subseteq A$ where $S \neq \emptyset$ such that $\forall p,q \in S, f(p) = f(q) \Rightarrow p = q$.

---

Maybe, change the requirement $S \neq \emptyset$ to be $|S| > k$.

And, we should also ensure $\forall p \in S$,  $\forall q \in A$, $f(p) = f(q) \Rightarrow p = q$.

Comment: I'd simply say that $f$ is injective on the subset $S$. The existence of such an $S$ is not a remarkable property... If $A$ is non-empty, simply take $S$ to be a singleton.

Comment: I'm with @Mr.Chip. In general the existence of $S$ is not guaranteed. You could define  $S$ to be the maximal subset which $f$ is injective on. Maybe calling it the "injective core." But I've never encountered such a definition.

Comment: It can also be rephrases as: "$f\circ\iota_S$ is injective" where $\iota_S:S\to A$ denotes the inclusion.

Comment: If we take $S$ to be a maximal subset in which $f$ is injective, then $S$ is a set of representatives of equivalence classes for the equivalence relation $\ker f$ on $A$ given by $(a_1,a_2) \in \ker f$ iff $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. But again, there is nothing remarkable about it, since this equivalence relation can always be defined (and it is trivial, i.e., $\{(a,a):a \in A\}$ whenever $f$ is injective).